# Laravel 5.6 - Get Route By Name In Controller

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

Within my login controller there is a hardcoded URL string which sets where to redirect to once the user has logged in. I am trying to make this dynamic by getting the route by name:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Updated To:

```
protected $redirectTo = route('home');
```

However the above give the following error:

> FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   Constant expression contains invalid operations

Is it possible to get the URL to the route by its name?

Comment: look in the middleware directory, there is an auth file, thats the place

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
request()->route()->getName()
```

To get the url you would use

```
request()->url()
```

And the path

```
request()->path()
```

Current route method

```
request->route()->getActionMethod()
```

In the case of `redirectTo` you can override the function:

```
protected function redirectTo() {
    return route('foo.bar');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're not allowed to use a function call when declaring a property in your class. You should use your controller's constructor to set it:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->redirectTo = route('home');
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can define a `redirectTo` method which returns the location that you want the user to be redirected to after a successful login. You can then remove the `$redirectTo` property altogether:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function redirectTo()
    {
        return route('home');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a route named `home`
like this:

`Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');`
or `Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get route url

```
$route_url = \Request::route()->getURLByName("name of the route");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $redirectTo = route('home');
```

You cannot assign a function to property. That's why you are getting this error.

you can do this in your constructor like

```
public function __construct(){

  $this->redirectTo = route('home')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way which i use and it will work with you.just put this function in your LoginController to override authenticated function.

```
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
            return redirect()->route('your_route_name');
    }
```